# Разделение текста в массив

Tags: php

Вот есть такая строчка: "/test 123 test 5-6 test 8 test". Все циферки кроме букв test, могут изменяться, подскажите, пожалуйста, как их записать в массив, количество пробелов одинаковое -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "/test 123 test 5-6 test 8 test";
preg_match_all(/(test\s*[-\d]*)+/,$str,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);//[0] => Array ( [0] => test 123 [1] => test 5-6 [2] => test 8 [3] => test )
```

По поводу

```
/(test\s*[-\d]*)+/
```

`/ и /` вокруг - ограничители. Они сообщают, что именно внутри есть регулярка. 
`\s` - пробел(и еще несколько символов, которые как он выглядят)
`\s*` - сколько угодно пробелов, 0-inf
`[]` - символьный класс
`[-\d]` - символьный класс, состоящий из цифр и дефисов. Дефис в этом значении ВСЕГДА в начале.
`()` - группировка. В общем, она тут не очень нужна.
`+` - любое ненулевое число раз. В данном случае тоже не нужно, так как используется preg_match_all

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $str = "/test 123 test 5-6 test 8 test";
$a = explode(' ', $str); ?>
```

Так не устроит?

Comment: Я бы скорее сделал 

    explode('test ',$str);